# How to create a unique string/key form JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, stringify

I would like to create a unique string/ key/ identifier/ hash from object's values. For example:

```
let myObj =
{
  key1: 'val1',
  key2: 'val2',
  key3: 'val3',
  key4: 'val4'
};

function getObjectUniqueKey(obj) {
  return (`${ obj.key1 }|${ obj.key2 }|${ obj.key3 }|${ obj.key4 }`);
}
```

The method `getObjectUniqueKey()` will work fine, however it isn't scale to bigger objects (my objects have more than 10 keys).

Is there any way in JavaScript to create a unique string that will represent an object? something similar to `JSON.stringify()` but isn't so robust?
(`JSON.stringify` will also stringify the keys, but all my objects have the same interface - same key's names - so stringifing them isn't needed).

1. `{ key: 'val1' }` and `{ key: 'val2' }` should produce **different** results.
2. `{ key1: 'val' }` and `{ key2: 'val' }` should produce **different** results.
3. `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` and `{ b: 2, a: 1 }` should produce the **same** result.

Comment: You can do `JSON.stringify(myObj)` and replace unnecessary thing other than numbers and alphabets `str.replace(/[\W\D]/g, '')`

Comment: @JonasWilms - I've updated my question, the problem with `JSON.stringify` is that it will also stringify the keys,

Comment: If you only need to map objects uniquely in ram, it's best to simply do `let m = new Map(); m.set(myObj, 'someCorrespondingValue'); m.set(anotherObj, 'anotherCorrespondingValue);`

Comment: Is it important for you that you can calculate the value of the object through the key or is it just important that it's unique?

Comment: Should `{ key: 'val1' }` and `{ key: 'val2' }` produce the same hash? Should `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` and `{ b: 2, a: 1 }` produce the same hash? Should `{ key1: 'val' }` and `{ key2: 'val' }` produce the same hash??

Comment: Can values be objects?

Comment: @JonasWilms - In my case no, values aren't objects.

Comment: @MatthiasGwiozda - What important to me is that 2 objects with the same values will generate the same hash/ key. I don't care about reversing the process - I don't need to take that new-key and convert it back to the original object.

Comment: @Gershom - I've updated my question, to answer your comment

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sorted array of all keys (to make sure that values with the same key are compared), then map those keys to the related values and use `JSON.stringify` on the array of values:

```
  JSON.stringify(
    Object.keys(obj)
    .sort()   
    .map(k => obj[k])
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 examples without JSON.stringify:

**Version1**:

```js
var myObj =
{
    key1: 'val2',
    key2: 'val1',
    key4: 'val4',
    key3: 'val3',
};

/**
 * get unique string (Version 1).
 * This is fine if every object has always the same keys.
 */
function getObjectUniqueKey(obj) {
var res = '';
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.sort()
    .forEach((key, i) => {
        res += obj[key]
        if (keys.length != i + 1) {
            res += '|'
        }
    });
return res;
}

console.log(`Version1: ${getObjectUniqueKey(myObj)}`);
```

**Version2:**

```js
var myObj =
{
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2',
    key4: 'val4',
    key3: 'val3',
};

/**
 * This Version can be used when the number of keys are changing.
 * This is based on your example that
 * { key1: 'val' } and { key2: 'val' } should produce different results.
 * 
 * Here you have to use a identificator for the key names because otherwise
 * the example objects would create the same result (v1 doesn't care about this).
 */
function getObjectUniqueKeyV2(obj) {
    var res = '';
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys
        .sort()
        .forEach((key, i) => {
            res += key + ':' + obj[key]
            if (keys.length != i + 1) {
                res += '|'
            }
        });
    return res;
}


console.log(`Version2: ${getObjectUniqueKeyV2(myObj)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

A sort is most likely needed if you want to produce the same hash regardless of key order. If you don't want to wind up with absurdly long keys for large objects you'll need some kind of lossy hashing to occur. Note that in order to fully hash an object, we need to be able to hash every type of value within the object. The logic below primarily hashes Arrays of Strings with `lossyHashStrs`. It can also convert an Object into an Array of Strings by collecting all keys and values into an Array. As mentioned, every value within the Object needs to be hashable. The below code handles String, Number, and Object values. It will choke if the Object includes an Array as a property, for example (but could be extended to handle this!)

Overall, hashes will be strings that appear like 12-digit decimal numbers, with leading zeros if necessary.

```js
// A utility function for checking variable types
let isType = (v, type) => (v == null && type == null) || v.constructor === type;

let lossyHashStrs = strs => {
  
  // Convert an Array of Strings into a String that looks like a 12-digit number
  
  let max = 999999999999;
  let n1 = 129837378393;
  let n2 = 348973984723;
  for (let str of strs) { // Loop over all strings...
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { // Loop over characters of the current string...
      // Some homebrewed hashing chaos, which factors in the current character
      n2 = (7 + n2 * n1 * str.charCodeAt(i)) % max;
      n1 = (11 + n1 * n2 + n2 * n2) % max;
    }
  }
  return `${n1}`.padStart(`${max}`.length, '0');
};

let lossyHashObj = obj => {
  
  // Convert an Object into an Array of Strings, then return the `lossyHashStrs` result
  
  let vals = [];
  let keys = Object.keys(obj).sort();
  for (let key of keys) {
    vals.push(key);
    let val = obj[key];
    
    // Ensure that `val` can be converted to a String:
    
    // If `val` is already a String, no dilemma!
    if (isType(val, String)) vals.push(val);
    
    // If `val` is a Number, simply use `toString`
    else if (isType(val, Number)) vals.push(val.toString());
    
    // If `val` is an Object recursively call `lossyHashObj` (yes - circular references will repeat infinitely)
    else if (isType(val, Object)) vals.push(lossyHashObj(val));
    
    // TODO:
    // else if (isType(val, Array)) /* ... */
    
    // Throw an Error for any other type of value
    else throw new Error(`Object contains a ${val.constructor.name}; don't know how to hash :(`);
    
  }
  return lossyHashStrs(vals);
  
};


let tests = [
  [ { a: 1 }, { a: 1 } ],
  [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 } ],
  [ { a: 1, b: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 1 } ],
  [ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 1 } ],
  [ { a: 2, b: 3 }, { b: 3, c: 4 } ],
  [ { c: 3, b: 2, a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } ]
]

for (let [ v1, v2 ] of tests) {
  
  let hash1 = lossyHashObj(v1);
  let hash2 = lossyHashObj(v2);
  console.log([
    `Compare:`,
    `  ${JSON.stringify(v1)} (hash: ${hash1})`,
    `  ${JSON.stringify(v2)} (hash: ${hash2})`,
    `Hashes match: ${(hash1 === hash2).toString().toUpperCase()}`
  ].join('\n'));
  
}
```